# Is it possible to insert a subview while being on the same tab bar index?

Tags: ios, objective-c

To give some context, I have logic that programmatically decides what view controller to insert into the navigation controller. For example:

```
If(true){

MyViewController * MyObject = [[MyViewController alloc]init];

myNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithViewController:MyObject];

else {
MyOtherViewController * MyOtherObject = [[MyViewController alloc]init];

myNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithViewController:MyOtherObject];
}

  self.tabBarController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:myNavigationController,nil];
```

Hopefully that illustrates my point of how I insert views inside of navigation controller. Now onto my problem:

I have an action listener with a button inside of "MyViewController" that essentially replaces the navigation/tab bar index when the user clicks the button. Is it possible to update a navigation/tab bar index with just a button?

```
 MyViewController.m 


- (IBAction)MyActionListener:(id)sender {
       MyOtherViewController *MyOtherObject = [[MyOtherViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyOtherViewController" bundle:nil];



                [self.view insertSubview:MyOtherViewController.view atIndex:2];
}
```

When I do this, I get a crash `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS` I'm just wondering if my implementation/approach is wrong. I noticed this question: [Update UITabBar Views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998117/update-uitabbar-views)
However, doesn't seem to fit the results I am looking for. Hopefully I am clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to switch your views on button click with navigation. 
You currently in VC1 , you have other two vc VC2 & VC3 and on button click you choose VC2 or VC3 but you did not change the VC1 place.

Comment: So you are saying something like: `[self.navigationController pushViewController:MyOtherObject animated:YES];`

Comment: ok thanks. Btw, you mean to say right, not "write." I originally tried it that way, problem is my app reuses that view controller over and over again. So I am in a situation where `self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;` needs to be no from view to view. I can easily wrap logic around it. Just trying to figure out most efficient option. Appreciate the help!